# Iframe a Hosted Paypage, sometimes reloads the Parent Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

Below is the process that The page takes

```
+-----------------------+                +------------------------+
|     Parent Page       |                |     Parent Page        |
|                       |                |                        |
|      Takes user       |                |       Feeds info v     |
|        inputs         |                |                        |
|   +---------------+   |                |   +----------------+   |
|   |               |   |                |   |   Hosted page  |   |
|   |               |   |                |   |                |   |
|   | not displayed |   |                |   |                |   |
|   |               +------------------> |   | Ask for credit |   |
|   |               |   |                |   |      info      |   |
|   |               |   |                |   |                |   |
|   +---------------+   |                |   +----------------+   |
|                       |                |                        |
+-----------------------+                +------------------------+


+-----------------------+                +------------------------+
|     Parent Page       |                |     Parent Page        |
|                       |                |                        |
|       waits           |                |   parent Refreshes     |
|                       |                | Parent goes to redirect|
|   +---------------+   |                |   +----------------+   |
|   |               |   |                |   |   Hosted page  |   |
|   |               |   |                |   |                |   |
|   | Checks data   |   |   success      |   |                |   |
|   | Charges fee   +------------------> |   |redirect trigger|   |
|   |               |   |                |   |                |   |
|   |               |   |                |   |                |   |
|   +---------------+   |                |   +----------------+   |
|                       |                |                        |
+-----------------------+                +------------------------+
            |                                                      
            |                                                      
            | Fails to charge                                             
            |                                                      
            v                                                
+-----------------------+                                          
|    Parent Page        |                                          
|                       |                                          
|                       |                                          
|   reload to redirect  |                                          
|      SOMETIMES        |                                          
|    MOSTLY doesn't!    |                                          
|  +-----------------+  |                                          
|  |   HOSTED page   |  |                                          
|  |                 |  |                                          
|  |Trigger redirect |  |                                          
|  |                 |  |                                          
|  |                 |  |                                          
|  |                 |  |                                          
|  +-----------------+  |                                          
|                       |                                          
+-----------------------+
```

The redirect should be going on inside of the Iframe only but it is triggered on the parent
and only sometimes, in the case of fail it almost always triggers inside the iframe, maybe 1/10 reloads.

Both redirect also has a POST data attached with basic payment info feedbacks

such as amount, what for, where, who ect.

What i need is for This to either `STOP` refreshing the page or `ALWAYS` do it

Since the code for this is Too board to post

(most of it on the hosted pay page called planet payment) so no direct access to how they actually do their redirects.

Comment: Explanations for lacking code or not, but how can you imagine anyone could solve the problem without seeing the code?

Comment: @Teemu I don't have the code. it is a hosted payment page, something like a paypal payment process where the cart directs you to paypal and does everything at paypal and then sends you back.

Comment: I was hoping it had something to do with https or some type of html/javascript that would force it to reload onto the parent or inside the iframe